# Write output of multiple python scripts to single file

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, cron, python

I used to have only one python script, of which the output would be directed to a log file.

It works like this, I have it in the autostart, using crontab.

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 30; sudo /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/admin/Desktop/main/main.py >> /home/admin/Desktop/main/log.log
```

This just waits 30 seconds after reboot to start the python script and direct the output to the log file.

Now I made a second python script, which basically watches over the activity of that script, but also writing any relevant data to that same log file. I added it just the same way I did the one before:

```
@reboot /bin/sleep 40; sudo /usr/bin/python3 -u /home/admin/Desktop/main/mainWatchdog.py >> /home/admin/Desktop/main/log.log
```

However, my problem right now is, that any output of the `watchdog` is not written to the log file. I am not too familiar with this topic, so I am not sure if it even is possible to write to the same file using this method.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the `watchdog` output is redirected to stderr. Try something like:  `python_pogram &>>/home/admin/Desktop/main/log.log` or `python_pogram >> /home/admin/Desktop/main/log.log 2>&1`

Comment: Not sure what you're running (you don't mention it), but consider using a `systemd` service instead of a crontab and collect logs using `journalctl` instead of logging to a file on disk.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? I'm afraid your command doesn't make sense. You are using `sudo -u` but not giving a user. Are you sure this ever ran? Do you want to run the script as root or as another user? What operating system are you using?